# PDO: Call to a member function errorInfo()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I read [this tutorial](http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements/) about PDO. I had an error and tried the errorInfo() function.
However, I get this error when trying to use errorInfo():

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in C:\Users\Nico\Dropbox\PHP\Vagex Clone\Website\pdo\select.php on line 8
```

I used this code as it's in the tutorial:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM notexistingtable'); //that was the error I had 

if (!$query) {
var_dump($query->errorInfo());
}
```

So - if I have an error like this, how do I correctly use the errorInfo() function?

Comment: You don't need errorInfo() function. [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php: errorInfo is a method of PDO (the instance is here `$db`) and not of `false` which is returned by the failing query.

So use `$db->errorInfo()` for getting the failure info.